# C++ Dining Philosopher Problem using C from GeeksForgeeks site

Tags: c

:D

My dear stackoverflow friends, I am working on my school project in
whick I have to analyse the soucre code from this page:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dining-philosopher-problem-using-semaphores/

```
#define LEFT (phnum + 4) % N
```

and my question for you is "Who is(or what is it, a type,a local variable...) phnum? ".

I will apriciete your answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes I did. I mean I am familiar with C and its # directives but I haven't used C for I while.
You are pointing to me that LEFT is taking an argument ?

Comment: Phnum seems to be just a name of an argument (of type int) passed to a function. Not a good way to declare #define really

Comment: It is, for example, the argument `phnum` in function `void put_fork(int phnum)`.

Comment: Learning C from geeksforgeeks is like learning driving from GTA.

Answer (score 0):

The statement #define LEFT (phnum + 4) % N defines a “macro” named LEFT whose replacement list is (phnum + 4) % N. The compiler does not need to know anything about the names in the replacement list; it simply remembers it.

When LEFT is seen later in the source code, the compiler replaces it with the replacement list, (phnum + 4) % N. Thus state[LEFT] != EATING becomes state[(phnum + 4) % N] != EATING.

After that replacement, the compiler interprets the names according to the declarations it has seen for them.

Conceptually, all of the “preprocessor” operations, such as defining macros, replacing them with their replacement lists, and processing #if and other statements marked with #, occur before the semantic analysis of the program. It is called “preprocessing” because historically it was done in a separate processing stage before compilation, even with a separate program. In modern compilers, the preprocessor operations may be interleaved with the rest of the compilation, but the results are the same.